# how to create threads to avoid IllegalThreadStateException

Tags: java, multithreading

It's a multithreading exercise in which i use a Monitor to synchronize threads. I don't have problem with monitor or syncronization, there is no deadlock. I want to create some threads in the main. Code below generates threads, adds them to an ArrayList and starts them. Generates different threads with a switch-case. Since every thread should be added to ArrayList and started, i put these two lines at the end of switch-case, to not write same code in every case-state. But in this way it launches an IllegalThreadStateException.

To make my code work, i can apply different approaches, but i have some doubts for all of them. Which one would be the most appropriate way to do it?

Creating a function which will create a new myThread instance, add it to the ArrayList and start it. But since i have to call it from main, or it should be static(as i know, creating a static function without a good reason is not a good practice) or i should call it like `new myClass().someMethod()` but since i have to create many new threads, it would create many instances of myClass, not seem good.

```
public class myClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       int scount=10, tcount=5, pcount=5;
       final int SIZE = 20;


       ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
       myMonitor monitor = new myMonitor(SIZE);
       User u = null;
       int s = 0, t = 0, p = 0; //counters

       //GENERATED CASUALLY DIFFERENT TYPE OF THREADS
       while(s < scount || t < tcount || p < pcount){

           int type = (int)(Math.random() * 3); 

           switch(type){
           case 0:
               if(p < pcount){
                  u = new User(monitor, p, "USER_TYPE_1");
                  p++;                  
               }
               break;
           case 1:
               if(t < tcount){
                   u = new User(monitor, p, "USER_TYPE_2");
                   t++;
               }
               break;
           case 2:
               if(s < scount){
                  u = new User(monitor, p, "USER_TYPE_2");
                  s++;
               }
               break;
           }
           users.add(u);
           u.start();
       }

   }

}
```

---

```
public class User extends Thread{
  myMonitor monitor;
  final private int number;
  final private String type;
  final private int k;
  final private int MIN = 1;
  final private int MAX = 5;


public User(myMonitor monitor, int number, String type) {
    this.monitor = monitor;
    this.number = number;
    this.type = type;
    this.k = (int)(Math.random() * ((MAX - MIN) + 1)) + MIN;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

@Override 
public void run(){

    for(int i=0; i<k; i++){

        switch(this.type){
            case "TYPE1":
                monitor.startType1();
                break;
            case "TYPE2":
                monitor.startType2(i);
                break;
            case "TYPE3":
                monitor.startType3();
                break;
        }

        try{

            Long duration = (long) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000);
            Thread.sleep(duration);
            System.out.printf("%s-%d used system for the %d.time. Took %d ms\n",
                    this.type, this.number, i+1, duration);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        switch(this.type){
            case "TYPE1":
                monitor.endType1();
                break;
            case "TYPE2":
                monitor.endType2(i);
                break;
            case "TYPE3":
                monitor.endType3();
                break;
        }

        try{
            Long duration = (long) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000);
            Thread.sleep(duration);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    System.out.printf("%s-%d finished\n", this.type, this.number);
}
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code makes absolutely no sense. You haven't been programming long with Java, have you?

Comment: It's just an multithreading example, since i don't have problem with synchronization etc. I didn't add the code. But now edited it, i hope it's more clear. But it doesn't depend on how long i program with java...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets carry out a thought experiment, `Math.random * 3` always returns `0` - this is possible because it's obviously [random](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25) (just unlikely).

*Iteration 1*

```
int s == t == p == 0
```

We enter the first case, as `type == 0`. We generate a new "P" `Thread` and `add` it to the `List` and `start()` it.

```
p++
```

*Iteration 2*

```
int s == t == 0; p == 1
```

We enter the first case, as `type == 0`. We generate a new "P" `Thread` and `add` it to the `List` and `start()` it.

```
p++
```

...

*Iteration 5*

```
int s == t == 0; p == 4
```

We enter the first case, as `type == 0`. We generate a new "P" `Thread` and `add` it to the `List` and `start()` it.

```
p++
```

*Iteration 6*

```
int s == t == 0; p == 5
```

We enter the first case, as `type == 0`. **We do nothing as p >= pcount**. Our `thrd` still points to the `Thread` we created in *Iteration 5*.

We add the **same `Thread`** to the `List` and `start()` it.

```
IllegalThreadStateException
```

Now, obviously `Math.random * 3` will return different values but it will return duplicates (and your code is designed around that) - so you **will** get this situation.

How to avoid it? Well, you do not actually *want* to generate random numbers:

```
final List<Integer> desiredValues = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2));
Collections.shuffle(desiredValues)
for(final Integer value : desiredValues) {
    //case switch
}
```

Comment: You right, i didn't realize this situation. Collection.shuffle() is a good advice. Thanks!

Comment: my IDE says that List is not generic, it cannot be parameterized with arguments...

Comment: Wrong `List`. Check your imports.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `thrd.start();` even if a new thread wasn't created. Since you've declared the variable outside of the loop, it'll still refer to the previously started thread. Calling `start()` twice on a thread will result in an exception.

Move `myThread thrd = null;` inside the `while` loop, and only call `start();` if it isn't null.

Comment: That's not really required - see my answer. The OP wants to generate a fixed set of values in a random order - not random values.

Comment: Well obviously not. I was going for the least amount of changes to the original.